# How to unlink react-native-firebase from IOS?

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase for notifications in my android application. It work well on android app.

In my IOS app i am using Apple Push Notifications (APNS) so, i don't want to link react-native-firebase to IOS. How can i unlink react-native-firebase from IOS only ? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the `android` folder to something else, run `react-native unlink 'package'` and then rename it back.

Not sure if there's an official way to do it tho